# Minimal Raspbian with X GUI

Tags: xorg

I installed a minimal build of raspbian, and installed xorg on it. However, when I run `Xorg -configure`, it tells me that no devices were found. Starting X server via `xinit &` and sshing into the server via `ssh -X`, I still see that the `$DISPLAY` has no value set.

What might be the issue?

Comment: I used fbi  and framebuffer , not sure if it will work for you http://raspberrycompote.blogspot.com/2012/12/low-level-graphics-on-raspberry-pi-part_9509.html

Comment: This link might help http://vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html